# Is it possible to create a search engine with PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have recently ben working on a site where users can post whatever they want. Let's pretend 100'000 article get posted every month, it would be a pain to find what you need. This is why we have search bars on sites. Here's the part I understand: I know how to create a search bar and check every item in a database to see if it a match to the user's search term. Now for the part I don't understand: I do not understand how to retrieve every single item among thousands that are related to the search term and display them in a decent way. Allow me to elaborate. On google, it shows a certain amount of results per page and then you click a button to go to the next page. How can I re-create something like this?

```
include_once "mysql_connect.php";


$terms = $_POST["search"];

$fetchlast = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM allaccounts WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM allaccounts)");
$lastrow = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast);
$lastid = $lastrow[0];

for ($i=1; $i <= $lastid; $i++) { 

$current= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$i");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($current)) {
    $articlename= $row[0];
    $articleid= $row[1];
    $articleurl= $row[2];
 }
}
```

Here is what I have so far. This code skims through the entire database and stores the last entry it checked in a set of variables. I am going to have a different amount of returned articles for every different search term. How can I store the details of each one?

Comment: Have tried to figure it out yourself? You need SQL to make this done.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

To retrive related  data for users' search from database you can use "like" in the query:

=》select * from posts where  like '%$user_query%'

To show limited amount of results per page use 'pagination'. Search for pagination techniques.